# Get the row with the max date value with criteria - access 2007/2010

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

My main table, from which I take all the data from is "RequestTable" (I reduced it down to make it easier) in which I have:

```
ID_student
ID_professor
Date (and the three altogether are primary keys)
changeprofessor-note - if student wants to change the professor 
                       then he/she should write in that field a sentence 
                       why he/she wants to do the change

professor-reject-note - if the professor is not happy about the work of 
                        the student, then he can choose not to mentor that 
                        student anymore, leaving him without a mentor and the 
                        student should choose another mentor later.

ID-seminar- after choosing a mentor the students 
            can choose the seminar they want to work on

changeofSeminar-note - if the student wants to change the seminar 
                       then they need to write the reason why in here 
                       (then the ID of the new seminar should be written in 
                       the ID seminar field also)

IDapprove-reject - all approving or rejecting is going through this field
```

My initial theory was that the students could choose the mentor and the seminar in one row, but it seems too complicated now because I have no idea how to make everything work after changing mentors, declined mentoring, changing seminars and so on.

I set a more comfortable theory that all the students need to choose the mentor first. So that I could get easier the data of mentoring when needed. And I set "is null" in the query under the "ID_seminar" and "changeofseminar-note" because any changes on just the seminar part can't affect the rows where the students chosen their mentors/professors and got approved.

I implemented your code and got this:

```
SELECT [requesttable].ID_Student, Max([requesttable].Datum) AS MaxOfDatum,                                                                        First([requesttable].ID_Profesor) AS ID_Profesor, [requesttable].ID_status_odobrenja
FROM [requesttable]
WHERE ((([requesttable].ID_Student) Not In (SELECT  [ID_Student]

FROM  [requesttable]

WHERE  [IDapprove-reject] IS NOT NULL )))
GROUP BY [requesttable].ID_Student, [requesttable].IDapprove-reject, [requesttable].changeseminar-note, [requesttable].ID_seminar
HAVING ((([requesttable].IDapprovereject)=1) AND (([requesttable].changeseminar-note) Is Null) AND (([requesttable].Id_seminar) Is Null))
ORDER BY [requesttable].ID_Student, Max([requesttable].Datum), First([requesttable].ID_Profesor), [requesttable].IDapproved-reject;
```

And i get:

```
 3   12   1
15   11   1
55    5   1
```

And I need:

```
 3   6   1
15   6   1
52   5   1 - after being rejected by mentor 10, 
             the student choose another mentor (id 5) and got approved.
55   5   1
```

Old info below:

I got my query to this point and two other data are set to show only rows with null values to get this:

```
ID student Id professor date       professor-reject-note ID accept/reject
3          12           12.11.2012 null                     1 
3           6           13.11.2012 null                     1
52         10           12.11.2012 null                     1 
52         10           15.11.2012 NOT null                 1 
55          5           12.11.2012 null                     1
```

I want my results to be

```
3           6           12.10.2013 null                     1
15          6           7.1.2013   null                     1
55          5           12.11.2012 null                     1
```

Totally exclude StudentID 52 because of the professor-reject-note meaning the professor doesn't want to mentor the student anymore. Also I have a doubt about the ID accept/reject number in that option , maybe I could set it to 2 instead of 1 to make it easier. 1 means accepted, 2 would mean rejected, but if I set it to 2 and exclude the entire row I still can't get rid of the other ID 52 row. I'm a bit confused about it and have no clue how make it work.

If I set date to maxdate and Id professor to group by FIRST I almost get what I want, all the data is right except the Student ID 52 is still there - both rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT t.[id student],
       t.[id professor],
       t.DATE,
       t.[professor-reject-note],
       t.[id accept/reject]
FROM   atable t
WHERE  t.[id student] NOT IN 
    (SELECT [id student]
     FROM   atable
     WHERE  [professor-reject-note] IS NOT NULL)
```

Your field / column names could do with some work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think i did the same thing in query design mode. But now I tried with your code (i'm not sure if I did everything right because i have many tables connected in this query) but still is showing me the other ID Student 52 row, the one that have Is Null in the Reject-note and i want to exclude completely the ID_student 52 and every ID that is in the same situation as ID 52.

Comment: I am afraid that if you simplify the data you show, it gets very difficult to provide an answer. The above code will exclude ID 52 from a table with the data shown in your question. I tested before posting.

Comment: Remou! I don't know if you are payed for helping others here or not, but no matter that I owe you more than a huge thank you. I think I got it now, everything seems working and I couldn't figure it out without your help. More than thank you! :)

Comment: I added a new mentor for the ID_student 52 because he was rejected by the ID_professor 10 and now he don't want to show at all. I want him to appear if he finds a mentor later with the ID of the new mentor. I need it for the 'Currently mentoring' table that will get me the current mentor for each student (if he has one).

Comment: No-one on Stackoverflow is paid (except the developers) all help is given freely. You should post revised data showing what you now have.

Comment: Please post sample data, like your first post. I might get round to this tomorrow, or perhaps someone else will pick up. It is best to format your posts as shown in my recent edits.

Comment: Remou, I really appreciate your help. I think the problem is in the main table "requesttable" from which I get data from. I should have made another table "kindofrequest" and put the foreign key to the requesttable to avoid mess with the ID_approved-rejected. With this structure I need a code that will look trough all fields and if in one I have something to recognise the type of request from that. It seems possible but thats was not smart at all. Now I'm in a big mess with the sortings and didn't get what I want for more than 48 hours. I think I'll change the tables and add new relations. :/

Comment: That sounds sensible. It can help to post your schemas and ask for help in the design, if you are not sure where you are going.

Comment: But thanks for your help. I'm thankful as it worked and definitely I learned something new. Have a nice day and even more than that :)

Comment: For now I'm ok. I'll post if I get stuck. Hope I wont. :/

Comment: Ramou, I'm stuck again, I got my problem here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774166/how-can-i-set-and-change-the-value-in-one-field-from-query-can-i-get-the-exact . Any help is welcome.